# How to get hints from a int c++

Tags: c++

How do we do to get a hint from a int , for example :

```
#define A 0x1
#define B 0x2

int hint = A | B;
```

How to check what hint is used ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, don't define constants as pre-processor `#define`s. Prefer real constants, like `enum`s.
If the constants are going to be used in bitfields, it also helps to write them out as binary literals using the `0b` suffix:

```
enum {
    A   = 0b001, // 0x1
    B   = 0b010, // 0x2
    BA  = 0b011, // 0x3
    C   = 0b100, // 0x4
    CA  = 0b101, // 0x5
    CB  = 0b110, // 0x6
    CBA = 0b111  // 0x7
};
```

You can create the same table using binary `OR` (`|`) for the combinatons containing more than one set bit:

```
enum {
    A   = 0b001,   // 0x1
    B   = 0b010,   // 0x2
    BA  = (B|A),   // 0x3
    C   = 0b100,   // 0x4
    CA  = (C|A),   // 0x5
    CB  = (C|B),   // 0x6
    CBA = (C|B|A)  // 0x7
};
```

You can then check if your `hints` contains a certain bit pattern by applying a binary `AND` (`&`) operation which returns a number with all the bits set that are set in both operands (`hints` and `BA`) and then checking the result:

```
if((hints & BA) == BA) {
    // hints has both A and B set (and possibly more)
}
```

Two examples:

```
  hints: 0b111
&    BA: 0b011
--------------
         0b011  (equal to BA)
```

```
  hints: 0b110
&    BA: 0b011
--------------
         0b010  (not equal to BA)
```

If you want to check if `hints` has *any* of the bits in `BA` set, just exclude the check for equality with `BA`:

```
if(hints & BA) {
    // either B or A or both are set
}
```

Comment: Is "hint" an official term? I was thinking about title of this post should be "How to get bitwise flag"

Comment: @LouisGo No, it's an an official term afaik. I just interpreted _hint_ as a variable in OP:s code.

Answer (score 2):

Is's very simple just use this operation

```
if ((hints & hint) == hint)
```

in your example it goes

```
if ((hint & A) == A)
```